# Xcode scheme change display name

Tags: ios, xcode, build

I have a custom Xcode build scheme that moves some files to toggle between dev and prod variables. Can I change the app display name in the dev scheme as well?

For example, if the app name is "MyApp", it currently shows up on the home screen as "MyApp". Can I configure my dev build scheme so that it shows up on the home screen as "MyApp Dev"? I tried setting `TARGET_NAME="MyApp Dev"` in a pre-action build script, but it doesn't seem to work.

Xcode 7, iOS 9

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can do that easily.

1. Add a "User-Defined Setting" (e.g. DISPLAY_NAME) to your target and set different values for different Schemes.
2. Go to the "Info.plist" of your target and add "Bundle display name" key and set its value to "$(DISPLAY_NAME)"

Comment: Still in "General" tab it does not keep the Display Name disabled saying <Mulitple Values> as it should (it does this with Bundle Identifier). This means this it does not get the "per-configuration" value. I am with XCODE 11.

Comment: For my above comment, please see related post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60971887/xcode-how-to-use-multiple-display-name-values-different-per-each-configurati

Answer (score 9):

In Xcode 8 (at least), in your build settings you should already have a setting called "Product Name" (under "Packaging"). That will take different values for different schemes, although they all default to "$(TARGET_NAME)". That's why, if you don't specify the display name, it takes the target name.

You can change any or all of them.

This way, you don't have to create a new user-defined setting.

Comment: fyi -- Product Name is also used to create your .app file name, at least in Xcode 9

Answer (score 6):

This works for Xcode 9.

1. Target (General tab)-> **Display name** - $(PRODUCT_NAME)
2. In Build settings tab, search for **Product Name** and give the required product name under each schemes.

Comment: This does not work in Xcode 11.3.1. The result is to have a display name of literally $(PRODUCT_NAME) inside the file, and all scheme values are overwritten to this.

Comment: Please see related post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60971887/xcode-how-to-use-multiple-display-name-values-different-per-each-configurati