# Xcode: How to use multiple "Display Name" values, different per each configuration?

Tags: ios, xcode

In Xcode we use multiple configurations to compile several different apps, with different Bundle IDs and Display Names.

While the "Identity -> Bundle Identifier" correctly shows a greyed-out "" read-only value, this is not the same with the "Identity->Display Name", resulting to a common name for all configurations.

Note that we have added different values on the "Build Settings -> Product Name" property for each configuration, since our Info.plist entry for CFBundleDisplayName is $(PRODUCT_NAME).

We tried to have a blank "Identity->Display Name" and initially this worked (the Name was eventually the one provided by the configuration's "Build Settings -> Product Name").

However, at some point (when switching Schemes we think) the "Identity->Display Name" took again a generic name (the one used for the .app filename) and this caused all the different "Build Settings -> Product Name" values to be replaced by this same generic name.

Is this a bug? What should we do to NOT have the "Identity->Display Name" editable and rather get its value from the configuration values (like the Bundle ID does)?

Note: We also tried all suggestions provided here: [Xcode scheme change display name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33201489/xcode-scheme-change-display-name/46607336)
They did not work, see some comments below the answers there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update for Xcode 14 and up: you can click the `+` icon behind the text input of `Display Name` (under `Identity` in the `General` tab) and set a value for each build configuration.

For older versions of Xcode:

After you have created different build configurations, you can use a user defined setting per build configuration that sets the display name.

In order to do this you need to click on the `Build Settings` tab, and in the build settings tab you need to click on the `+` icon in the left upper corner and then select `Add User-Defined Setting`. A new entry in the user defined settings (at the bottom of the `Build Settings` tab) will be created with the name `NEW_SETTING`. Rename this to whatever you want, e.g. `APP_DISPLAY_NAME`. If you expand this setting (by clicking on the chevron icon to the left of it) you can set a value for each build configuration.

Now go back to the `General` tab and for the `Display Name`, fill in your user defined setting like so: `${APP_DISPLAY_NAME}` (replace `APP_DISPLAY_NAME` with whatever you named your setting) and press enter. Each build config will use the value from the user defined setting as the display name now.

When using a user defined setting as the display name, it is not shown as `<Multiple values>`, however it does take its value from the user defined setting. You can see it changing by switching the scheme, cleaning and then switching from the `General` tab, and then switching back to the `General` tab.

Comment: Would you be willing to add details to make your answer a complete/self-contained description on how to have a display name per scheme?  Greetings from Amsterdam :-)

Comment: I've updated my answer, but the UI for this was actually improved in Xcode 14 so the question may be less relevant.

Comment: Dankjewel Thijs! I'm on Xcode 14.x and did see the tiny `+` button, but didn't know what it was for.

Comment: It tried the `+` button but I'm seeing the Info.plist name, not the new name. Then tried deleting the Info.plist item after which the product name was used; so also not the new name. What could I be missing?

Comment: When you say "seeing the Info.plist name", do you mean in the display name textinput? Is your scheme using the correct build config?
When I change it through the `+` button it adds a    INFOPLIST_KEY_CFBundleDisplayName value to the build config in the proj.pbxproj file.